# How to calculate first repetition of a looping function?

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I'm new to Python and have a problem with the following assignment.

```
import random
print(random.randint(1, 100))
```

How do I calculate after how many random numbers there is a repetition (using dictionary)?

output is supposed to look like this:

```
    >>> repeat (1, 100)
    ([random1, random2, random3, ...], number of loops until the first repetition is reached)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an advanced solution.

First, create a generator of random numbers:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(100) # to make it repeatable
>>> it = iter(lambda: random.randint(1,100), -1)
```

This is the less known form of the function `iter`: the first argument is a function that is called until the sentinel is reached. Since `randint` will never return `-1`, this is an infinite generator of random numbers:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.islice(it, 15))
[19, 59, 59, 99, 23, 91, 51, 94, 45, 56, 65, 15, 69, 16, 11]
>>> list(itertools.islice(it, 15))
[95, 59, 34, 7, 85, 83, 27, 43, 30, 40, 99, 27, 23, 19, 25]
```

You can get as many random numbers as you need. (The function `islice` takes a "slice" of the iterator). Now, we take numbers while the number is not known:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x not in seen and not seen.add(x), it))
[45, 48, 81, 53, 27, 52, 60, 72, 36, 49, 21, 84, 82, 16, 24, 1, 78, 51, 19, 100, 73]
```

Note the side effect: we create an empty set `s` to store the seen numbers and, for each `x`, we test if `x` is in `seen` (we saw `x` before) *and then* add `x` to `seen`. The trick is that `seen.add(x)` always return `None`, thus `not seen.add(x)` is always `True` and `b and not seen.add(x) == b and True == b`.

To check:

```
>>> random.seed(100) # to make it repeatable
>>> it2 = iter(lambda: random.randint(1,100), -1)
>>> list(itertools.islice(it2, 30, 52))
[45, 48, 81, 53, 27, 52, 60, 72, 36, 49, 21, 84, 82, 16, 24, 1, 78, 51, 19, 100, 73, 21]
```

`21` was repeated.

Comment: -1: This is a very wrong concept of "advanced". It's not advanced at all, it's just pointless complexity. There is no reason in the world for which this should be considered a reasonable solution for this problem, and yet for some strange human behavior problem this kind of overcomplexity is somehow fascinating. My idea is this was just a juvenile problem for programmers, but others told me that experience in overcoming it is not the key factor. Anyway once again the worst in the pack is the winner, damaging the learner and reinforcing answer author misconception.

Comment: @6502 I didn't expect my answer to be accepted (and would not be angered if it was "unaccepted"), because it was not meant to be the main answer to this question, rather to give an insight (to the OP and other readers) on how this problem could be solved differently. That's why I wrote a small preamble to my answer (the word "advanced" was perhaps not the right one: the goal was to signal that this answer should be considered after the more obvious ones, not to say that it was better than the others).

Comment: I think you will agree that this answer is just another implementation of the idea behind other answers (including yours): 1. create the numbers; 2. store them in a  `set`; 3. stop on the first duplicate. So I guess that's the implementation that you find bad, because of its overcomplexity. The usage of `iter` seems simple to me. The `and not seen.add(x)` part is tricky, but that's a well known trick. I wanted to create an infinite iterator and see if it was possible to stop on the first duplicate, that's all.

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't use this code in production, but production is not the ultimate goal of every piece of code. Of course, this is not what you need when you learn Python. But I hope this answer has the right to exist.

Answer (score 3):

You could just initialize a set, then in a loop get one single random number and check if it's already in the set and quitting if this is the case, otherwise adding it to the set and continuing if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

`set` is more suitable here than `dict`, because you just want to record the repeatment, value in `dict` is useless here, O(1) time to check repeatment in `set`:

```
import random
def repeat(a, b):
    nums = set()
    count = 0
    while len(nums) == count:
        nums.add(random.randint(a, b))
        count += 1
    return list(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using a dictionary tho, but a function `repeat`:

```
import random
def repeat(a, b):
    l = []
    while True:
        l.append(random.randint(a, b))
        if len(set(l)) != len(l):
            break
    return l

print(repeat(1, 100))
```

Output:

```
[13, 76, 32, 41, 59, 34, 43, 91, 28, 17, 53, 20, 46, 67, 37, 88, 16, 6, 92, 34]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a list, and keep adding you random numbers in that list, and when you find that your random number is already in your list, you break the loop Note that this is an O(n) solution sine you need to find the element in the whole list

```
import random

my_list = []

while True:
    #Generate random number
    i = random.randint(1, 100)
    #If it is already in the list, break the loop
    if i in my_list:
        break
    #Append random number to list
    my_list.append(i)

print(my_list)
```

Output might look like

```
[5, 58, 84, 53]
[5, 29, 64, 52, 69, 53, 72, 41, 58, 50, 4, 68, 67, 22, 90, 32, 45, 17, 47, 89, 55, 6, 7, 46, 37, 88]
[17, 65, 46, 84, 30, 100, 48, 31, 80, 97, 70, 86, 47, 81, 13, 85, 60, 63, 22, 68, 8, 36, 99]
.....
```

An O(1) suggestion already pointed out by @6502 is to instead append your random numbers as keys of a dictionary, that lookup will be faster `O(1)`

```
import random

my_dict = {}

while True:
    #Generate random number
    i = random.randint(1, 100)
    #If it is already in the keys of dict, break the loop
    if i in my_dict:
        break
    #Append random number as key of dict with value 0
    my_dict[i] = 0

print(list(my_dict.keys()))
```

We can actually check the improvement using `timeit` module, although it's not appreciable since the random number size is only 1-100

First for the list approach

```
In [21]: import random 
    ...:  
    ...: def get_list(): 
    ...:     my_list = [] 
    ...:     while True: 
    ...:         #Generate random number 
    ...:         i = random.randint(1, 100) 
    ...:         #If it is already in the list, break the loop 
    ...:         if i in my_list: 
    ...:             break 
    ...:         #Append random number to list 
    ...:         my_list.append(i) 
    ...:     return my_list 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [22]: %timeit get_list()                                                                                                                                                                                           
16.9 µs ± 720 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Then for the dict approach

```
In [27]:                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [27]: import random 
    ...:  
    ...: def get_list(): 
    ...:     my_dict = {} 
    ...:     while True: 
    ...:         # Generate random number 
    ...:         i = random.randint(1, 100) 
    ...:         # If it is already in the keys of dict, break the loop 
    ...:         if i in my_dict: 
    ...:             break 
    ...:         # Append random number as key of dict with value 0 
    ...:         my_dict[i] = 0 
In [29]: %timeit get_list()                                                                                                                                                                                           
16.1 µs ± 567 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But the difference is appreciable if we use a range of say 1-10000

```
In [38]: import random 
    ...:  
    ...: def get_list(upper): 
    ...:  
    ...:     my_list = [] 
    ...:     while True: 
    ...:         # Generate random number 
    ...:         i = random.randint(1, upper) 
    ...:         # If it is already in the list, break the loop 
    ...:         if i in my_list: 
    ...:             break 
    ...:         # Append random number to list 
    ...:         my_list.append(i) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [39]: %timeit get_list(10000)                                                                                                                                                                                      
287 µs ± 5.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [40]: import random 
    ...:  
    ...: def get_list(upper): 
    ...:    
    ...:     my_dict = {} 
    ...:  
    ...:     while True: 
    ...:         # Generate random number 
    ...:         i = random.randint(1, upper) 
    ...:         # If it is already in the keys of dict, break the loop 
    ...:         if i in my_dict: 
    ...:             break 
    ...:         # Append random number as key of dict with value 0 
    ...:         my_dict[i] = 0 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [41]:  %timeit get_list(10000)                                                                                                                                                                                     
155 µs ± 2.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

You can see that the list approach took almost twice the time as the dict approach!

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence in which the numbers were generated is not to be maintained, you can use a dictionary to do this.

```
import random
def repeat_generator(min, max):
    random_dict = {}
    while True:
        random_number = random.randint(min, max)
        if random_dict.get(random_number):
            break
        else:
           random_dict[random_number] = 1
    print(random_dict.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. This adds each random number into a dict and then uses it to check if the random number already exists. You can do the same thing using other data structures, but, since you have mentioned dictionary, I have used it here.

```
import random

rand_dict = {}

i = 0
while True:
    rand_num = random.randint(1,100)
    if rand_num in rand_dict:
        print("random number already in dict. rand_num = %s, Number of Loops = %s" %(rand_num, i))
        break
    else:
        i += 1
        rand_dict[rand_num] = 1
```

**Output:**

```
random number already in dict. rand_num = 90, Number of Loops = 11
```